# Decreasing Limits of Elements of a Set

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $R_b=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}:f(x)<b\}$.

Consider $L_b=\bigcup_\limits{\varepsilon>0}\bigcap_\limits{r\in R_b}[r-\varepsilon,r].$

My question:

(1) How do you translate the above set statement into $\delta-\varepsilon$ statement?

(2) Why is $L_b$ the set of points on $\mathbb{R}$ that are decreasing limits of elements of $R_b$?

(3) What does it mean to be a decreasing limits of elements of a set? Is there an exact definition for this statement?

Comment: Where are the limits In the given formula? Sets do not translate into infinintesimals.